# the design of inner function _S_oom_malloc in SGI-STL allocator

Tags: stl, allocator, sgi

The code is as follows:

```
template <int __inst>
void*
__malloc_alloc_template<__inst>::_S_oom_malloc(size_t __n)
{
    void (* __my_malloc_handler)();
    void* __result;

    for (;;) {
        __my_malloc_handler = __malloc_alloc_oom_handler;
        if (0 == __my_malloc_handler) { __THROW_BAD_ALLOC; }
        (*__my_malloc_handler)();
        __result = malloc(__n);
        if (__result) return(__result);
    }
}
```

I have two questions.
1. why does _S_oom_malloc use infinite loop?
2. as we known, _S_oom_malloc will be called when malloc fails in __malloc_alloc_template::allocate function. And why does it use malloc to allocate space?

Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the loop is not truly infinite. There are two exits: by throwing a `BAD_ALLOC` exception an by allocating the requested amount of memory. The exception will be thrown when the current new-handler is a null pointer.

To understand how that can happen, consult e.g. Item 49 from [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876). Essentially any new-handler can either

- Make more memory available
- Install a different new-handler
- Deinstall the new-handler (i.e. passing a null pointer to `set_new_handler`
- Throw an exception
- `abort` or `exit`

Second, the reason that it uses the C library's `malloc` to allocate space is that `malloc` on most systems is a well-tested and efficiently implemented function. The Standard Library's `new` functions are "simply" exception-safe and type-safe wrappers around it (which you as a user can also override, should you want that).

Comment: thanks a lot, and what's the function of __my_malloc_handler?

Comment: it's just a local function pointer that refers to the current new-handler (which could be reset by `__malloc_alloc_oom_handler`).

Comment: glad to have been of help!